# Issue connecting iPhone XS (iOS 16.2) in Developer Mode enabled to M1 Macbook pro (macOS 13.1)

Tags: ios16, macos-ventura

I am trying to run my React Native IOS app on my iPhone XS device. iPhone connects to my M1 MacBook pro and I can access the phone but when I try to run the app Xcode complains that the device's developer mode is not enabled. But when I enable the Developer Mode the iPhone doesn't connect to the mac, it appears in the sidebar for a few seconds and then disappears.

Can anyone point out what the issue is? How can I connect the developer-mode enabled iPhone to my M1 Mackbook (Ventura macOS 13.1)?

Answer (score 0):

It's REALLY unintuitive but I was able to get it working by trying to build in XCode using the disabled device. It of course failed, but that caused the Developer Mode option to appear. Then I could turn it on and restart etc. From what I've read, the setting only appears if certain apps require it... or apparently if XCode tries to build a local app...